# BitMiracle.LibTiff.Net Converting oJPEG tiff to Bitmap results in a negative color image

Tags: c#, libtiff, libtiff.net, bitmiracle

I'm using the [BitMiracle.LibTiff](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) v2.4.560.0 to convert oJPEG tiffs to Bitmap.  This has worked out great until just recently.  A Tiff, that I tried converting, is a document with a white background and black text.  After converting the tiff, the result ends up with a black background and white text.

I'm using this [Convert from Tiff to Bitmap](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/html/4f1836a4-ed48-48f0-9c2d-5cf81ffb9303.htm) sample for my conversion.

Is this a bug with the BitMiracle.LibTiff library or does there need to be modifications to the sample code?  I made quite a few attempts of modifying the sample code, but with no success.

Comment: Can you properly decode the image with the original libtiff? If yes, can you provide the image for testing purposes?

Comment: @Bobrovsky, I haven't tried using the original libtiff, since I'm coding in C#.  As far as providing the image for testing, I cannot do that as the image contains sensitive material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the image that causes the issue has a TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC of Photometric.MINISWHITE. Changing that property to Photometric.MINISBLACK resolves the issue.

Added this snippet to [Convert from Tiff to Bitmap](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/html/4f1836a4-ed48-48f0-9c2d-5cf81ffb9303.htm)

```
FieldValue[] value = tif.GetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC);
if (value[0].ToInt() == (int)Photometric.MINISWHITE)
{
    tif.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.MINISBLACK);
}
```